# $_SESSION var other than string

Tags: php, session

I'm working on my first project using the superglobal `$_SESSION` so it's still pretty new to me.

What I need is to store an integer into `$_SESSION["role"]` but when I affect it an integer value it stores it as a String :

```
$_SESSION["role"] = serviceRole::getRoleByCuID($commonUser->getID());
```

Where `serviceRole::getRoleByCuID()` returns an integer.

Do I ***have*** to cast my variables everytime I use them or is there a simple trick to pass other type in my superglobal ?

My issue is on an if statement :

```
if ($_SESSION["role"] != DEV){
    //Always goes there even though $_SESSION["role"] equals "1" (String)
    //and DEV is an integer constant that equals 1
    echo "You're not a developer";
}
```

Comment: Well, even `"1"` equals `1`, so that's *not* your issue.

Comment: @deceze Well it seems like it was... Doing `if ($_SESSION["role"] != DEV+"")` did the trick, is there no clean way to do this ?

Comment: Your values simply aren't what you think they are. `var_dump($_SESSION['role'], DEV)` to see what you're actually trying to deal with.

Comment: @deceze Well I'm using XDebug with Netbeans so I do know what my values are ! I'll try your way to make sure but do you know where does `var_dump` is supposed to output in Netbeans 8.0 ? I have an "Output" view but it stays empty D:

Comment: The same place the `echo "You're not a developer"` outputs to. Simply substitute your variables for what you think they are: `if ("1" != 1) ...`. Won't go into the `if`.

Comment: Well it's working now, and I did not change anything W/ `$_SESSION["role"] != DEV`

Answer (score 2):

But you have to echo `DEV` and `$_SESSION["role"]` and check first if both values are same, because type cast is not the issue in this case.

```
if ((int)$_SESSION["role"] != DEV){
//Always goes there even though $_SESSION["role"] equals "1" (String)
//and DEV is an integer constant that equals 1
echo "You're not a developer";
}
```